# Converting css style to React Native stylesheet

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm currently using stylesheet for my style in react-native. I found a css style that I need for my component unfortunately it has an :after and :before in css. How to use :after and :before in stylesheet in react-native.
Here's the sample css code that I'm trying to convert into react-native style sheet:

```
.ticket:before,
.ticket:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ticket:before {
  background: white;
  left: -30px;
}

.ticket:after {
  right: -30px;
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css pseudo selectors such as `::after` or `::before` do not work in react-native, but if you want your styles to look as close to css as possible I would recommend using something like [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics). It works on both web and react-native.